# Which control does launchpad use?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, osx-lion

I'm new to Mac dev, just learning now :)
I'm very interesting with Launchpad in Lion, does anyone know which control it use? Or it uses a customized control?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The scrolling/swiping part seems to be a replica of iOS's UIPageControl, but I can't seem to find a cocoa equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Launchpad uses a standard/public Cocoa class. You might be able to use a heavily customized NSScrollView to get the same effect, but there's no "drag and drop" control in Interface Builder that gives you the same appearance and behavior.